# How can I load a .pod File from an URL in COCOS3D

Tags: iphone, ios, 3d, cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

I am making an app and I want to load some 3d models who are stored in a server. I can easily acces them in the browser with a link.

The idea of the app is that you have a menu and you can select which model do you want to see.

Answer (score 3):

In cocos3D you can create a node from a pod file by simply executing:

```
[CC3PODResourceNode nodeFromResourceFile:podFileName];
```

[Here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/19375) you can find a full working sample.

If your pod file is available online, you could first download it locally:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:YOUR_URL_HERE];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

then pass `filePath` to `nodeFromResourceFile`.

`filePath` identifies a file residing in the user documents directory (one of the few places where you can write files to, under iOS):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PODFILE.pod"];
```

If you want to save to a temporary directory, use:

```
NSTemporaryDirectory()
```

instead of `documentsDirectory`.

Comment: yes, I am using coco3d. My question is how, in cocos3d, can I load a .pod file or similar from an URL and not from a file. in the hello-world example it simply says: 
[self addContentFromPODResourceFile: @"somePodFile.pod"];

Comment: Thanks Sergio, but I dont have the FILES of the .pod files, I want to dynamically load them from different URLS..
(in your example I wanted to load this pod http://www.renderplace.com/misc/earth.pod but dynamically, I mean the pod downloads itself when the user uses the app and not come with the app.)

Comment: another quick question.. Where is filepath? I mean how can I access or declare it? sorry for the dumb question =/ and thanks!

Comment: it somehow doesnt work. I do this:
 <code>
 NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:Url];
 NSString *filePath = @"/tmp/locaPod.pod";
 
 [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
 
 if (urlData != nil) {
  NSLog(@"DATA NOT EMPTY!!");
 }
 [self addContentFromPODResourceFile: filePath];
       </code>

I get this error:

[***ERROR***] Could not load POD file '/Users/myUserName/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/3D121B77-EA25-42CD-A58E-36D8C58ED9DD/myApp.app/tmp/locaPod.pod'

Comment: maybe the POD isn't using a compatible format supported by cocos3d? From what I understand POD isn't POD, there may be newer and older file versions, and multiple programs can create POD files but do they all adhere to the standard - if there is one.

Comment: I can load the pod file fine if I use the traditional way, ie. via addContentFromPODResourceFile. If I try to do the same with the code I provided, it simply throws the error that it can't load the file. Btw how do you write code here? my comment looks aweful.
Thanks!

Comment: I suspect the issue is with trying and use directly `/tmp`... see my edit for some hint.

Comment: Thanks sergio! unfortunately it still doesnt work! this error arises:
[***ERROR***] Could not load POD file '/Users/(myUsername)/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/3D121B77-EA25-42CD-A58E-36D8C58ED9DD/homy2.app/Users/(myUsername)/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/3D121B77-EA25-42CD-A58E-36D8C58ED9DD/Documents/PODFILE.pod'

Comment: this is the code:
this is my code..
NSURL *Url = [NSURL URLWithString:(myurl)];
 
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PODFILE.pod"];
 
 NSMutableData *urlData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:Url];
 [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
  [self addContentFromPODResourceFile: filePath];

Comment: If you are sure that the file is there (correctly created), then the only thing I can suggest is stepping into `addContentFromPODResourceFile` and see why is failing... If there is a POD format issue, if you have control on those files, you could try and kind of "normalize" them (e.g., loading in blender and exporting again)...

Comment: I am not sure. How can I check that the file is corrrectly created?

Comment: You can, e.g, read the file into memory (`dataWithContentsOfFile:`) and then `NSLog` the returned `NSData` length.

Comment: Hi there again, i've tried everything and it just doesn't work! I fetched the data length, it is 
DATA 2 LENGTH:760340
and I obtained it via dataWithContentsOfFile length, but it just says the same error:
[***ERROR***] Could not load POD file: '(route)'

any suggestions? this thanks again sergio for your support..

Comment: So, if I understand you right, the file is not correctly stored locally. Then, you should check all of your paths. Add some NSLog to print the relevant information.